# How to get Value of Width Element in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Excel VBA to get value of element "width" which is changed from 0-100.
I want to get the value of width and compare continuously with some   variable using while loop, and when the value is reached to 100 then want to perform specific task. How can I do that. The screenshot is shared below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get this element by class name and get it's `style` attribute like this:

```
driver.findElementsByClassName("progress-bar").Attribute("style")
```

now you can find the substring and extract the width from there.

Comment: Thanks for help. I am beginner and not have much idea about this . How to find the substring and extract the width. Plz help

Comment: Getting an error: Object does not support this property

Comment: Do you have some delay / wait to allow the element appear before you finding it and trying to get it attribute?